# SVG CSS Animation issue

Tags: css, animation, svg, sass, frontend

I am trying to recreate this gif animation, but on a SVG. The SVG is the same icon as the gif. I am unsure how it's done with CSS.

This is the gif

[image]

```css
svg {
  width: 200px;
}

svg [data-name="right-line"] {
  transform: rotate(10deg);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 27.97 18.494">
    <g transform="translate(-.443292 0.304)">
      <g>
        <path d="M27.4,6.782c-7.609244-6.906331-19.218756-6.906331-26.828,0-.650213.586438-.76011,1.566067-.256,2.282l6.275,8.9c.444698.629922,1.252268.890007,1.981.638c1.738708-.602319,3.56592-.909558,5.406-.909h.007c1.84008-.000558,3.667292.306681,5.406.909.728522.251159,1.535402-.008297,1.981-.637l6.282-8.9c.50474-.715762.395717-1.69568-.254-2.283" transform="translate(.443-1.906)" fill="#9fbee8"/>
      <g>
        <line data-name="right-line" x1="0" y1="0" x2="7.313" y2="10.378" transform="translate(9.557 6.418001)" fill="none" stroke="#034ea2" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
        <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="7.313" y2="10.378" transform="translate(4.983 6.418001)" fill="none" stroke="#034ea2" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
        </g>
      </g>
    </g>
  </svg>
</div>
```

I have tried to rotating one of the lines, but it does not keep the position.

Just to test, if I can get it to rotate correct, so that I can create a keyframes anuimation for it

`[data-name="right-line"] { transform: rotate(10deg); }`

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet** using the `<>` icon.. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: In your codepen you have transformations in both lines and on the group holding the path and the lines. Also the path is translated. Try the following: delete the lines. Draw instead 2 vertical lines. Transform rotate the wiper blades around the starting point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then you specify transform/rotate in CSS you overwrite the transition/translate defined as an attribute. Either you define more transforms in the same attribute, or like in the following, wrap elements (line the line) in more grouping elements, so each element has its own transform.

```css
svg {
  width: 200px;
}

svg line {
  transform: rotate(-25deg);
  animation: wipe 500ms infinite alternate linear;
}

@keyframes wipe {
  from {
    transform: rotate(-25deg);
  }

  to {
    transform: rotate(25deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 28 17.1">
    <path d="M 27.41 5.2 c -7.61 -6.91 -19.22 -6.91 -26.83 0 c -0.65 0.59 -0.76 1.57 -0.26 2.28 l 6.28 8.9 c 0.45 0.63 1.25 0.89 1.98 0.64 c 1.74 -0.6 3.57 -0.91 5.41 -0.91 h 0.01 c 1.84 0 3.67 0.31 5.41 0.91 c 0.73 0.25 1.53 -0.01 1.98 -0.64 l 6.28 -8.9 c 0.51 -0.72 0.4 -1.7 -0.25 -2.28 Z" fill="#9fbee8"/>
    <g stroke="#034ea2" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round">
    <g transform="translate(17 16)">
      <line y2="-10.378" />
    </g>
    <g transform="translate(11 16)">
      <line y2="-10.378" />
    </g>
    </g>
  </svg>
</div>
```